# Can I visit the castles/fortresses in the mountains around Turin, Northern Italy?

Tags: italy, architecture, mountains

Three years ago I traveled from Turin to Paris by train, and saw amazing old castles all across the mountains. Are any of them available for a visit? I'm going to rent a car so the transport won't be a problem.

---

I forgot to say that I'm interested in the small castles or fortresses, not the famous ones. Something like that:
[image: Small castle]

Comment: In England and Scotland, there are castles where the owners will provide the equivalent of "bed and breakfast" in order to defray the expense of upkeep, meaning that you'd get to see at least part of the interior of the castle. I'd be very surprised if there weren't castles with similar arrangements in Italy, France, etc. Not to say that every castle would do this, but some probably would. You might check with local travel agents for specifics on availability and pricing. Or possibly call up the castles when you're in northern Italy (most have phones nowadays) and see if you can work a deal wi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [Forte di Bard](http://www.fortedibard.it/):

It's about an hour north from Turin, on the highway to Valle d'Aosta.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Check out Sacra di San Michele, about 45 minutes north of Torino:

http://www.sacradisanmichele.com/

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's one that you can definitely visit.

**Rivoli Castle**:

Cost: €6.50, free for under 11

Open: Tue-Thu 10am-5pm; Fri-Sun 10am-9pm

Comment: Thanks for the information, but this is far away from Turin :)

Comment: It's not, it's only 15 km from the center of Turin: http://g.co/maps/mtxfs It's a very beautiful place, and it hosts a contemporary art museum. Worth a visit if you are in Turino.

Answer (score 4):

Most of these castles are located in [Aosta Valley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aosta_Valley) (Italy).
I've driven around this place and also did the [Italian Job (Great St. Bernard Pass)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_St_Bernard_Pass).
If you plan to visit this part of Italy, I would also recommend the Great St. Bernard Pass (closed in winter).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the good suggestions you already received I'd like to add:

- [Forte di Bramafam](http://www.fortebramafam.it/): built between 1874 and 1889 it's one of the greatest fortifications of that period. It's in Val Susa, near Bardonecchia
- [Forte di Fenestrelle](http://www.fortedifenestrelle.com/)
  [image: Forte di Fenestrelle]
- [Rocca di Verrua Savoia](http://www.roccaverrua.it/)
  [image: Rocca Verrua Savoia]
- Batteria dello Chaberton
  [image: Batteria dello Chaberton]

[I assume something like Exilles is considered mainstream and so it wasn't included in this list]